# i'm trying to create one to one relationship between user to education but i'm only getting the result from education table not user

Tags: laravel, relationship, one-to-one

//User Model

```
public function education(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Education') 
}
```

//Education Model

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

//CONTROLLER

```
public function profile(Request $request){
    $user_info = User::find(1)->education;
    dd($user_info);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are asking for `education` relationship, which will return only `Education` data.

I would first eager load relationship:

```
$user_info = User::with('education')->find(1);
```

Now `$user_info` will contain `User` instance with `Education` relationship:

```
$user_info->name;
$user_info->email;

$user_info->education->title;
```